# Email alert to admin on account export through apex dataloader

Tags: email-alert, data-export

I would like to know if there is any standard functionality or any possible custom solution for making an email notification to the admin of the org when any data on account or other object is being exported from salesforce. Any tool can be utilised either the dataloader, Ant migration or else for exporting purpose but the email should be triggered to admin.

Example scenario:  When any user exports an account record through apex data loader, an email should be sent to admin stating this record have been exported by this user.

I have searched a lot through various forums and blogs but was not able to find a proper solution. Let me know if you need more detail. I am wondering even it is possible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No.

If you're concerned about users using these kind of tools, you can (a) run reports to see how users are logging in, (b) block logins from certain types of applications for some or all users, and/or (c) disable API Access entirely for users. It's a lot easier to simply configure your org correctly and hand out permissions when necessary, than to try and set up monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send an email to an admin for the scenario you have here.

You can though alternatively use [**Event Monitoring**](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro) to monitor activities in your Org.

It helps you to find out a User's activities which are logged in Event Log files capturing the different [Event Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_supportedeventtypes.htm). Based on the Event Type, you can determine what operation was performed by the User.